# HashMap to ComboBox

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, hashmap

im trying to get the values from the "teamPlayers" hashmap that correspond with the keys "i" and "j" in the "match" object to be placed into the comboBoxes "homebox, homebox2, awaybox, awaybox2". When i try to add four values to the comboboxes it only adds the last two. the  wondering if anybody has any idea i could try to stop this from happening and get it to add more values than the two its adding now. Thanks guys.

```
public void generateMatches (String homeTeam, String awayTeam){
        boolean bool = false;
        int x = 0;
        arrayLength = teamPlayers.size();

        for (String i : teamPlayers.keySet()){
            for (String j : teamPlayers.keySet()){
                if (teamPlayers.get(i).equals(teamPlayers.get(j)) && !bool){
                    bool = true;
                }else if (bool){
                    Match matches = new Match(i,j);
                    homeTeam = matches.getHomeTeam();
                    awayTeam = matches.getAwayTeam();
                    scoreHomeTeam.getItems().add(matches.getHomeTeam());
                    scoreAwayTeam.getItems().add(matches.getAwayTeam());

                    while(x<teamPlayers.size()){
                        for (Entry<String,String> e : teamPlayers.entrySet()){
                            homeBox.getItems().add(e.getValue());
                            homeBox2.getItems().add(e.getValue());
                            awayBox.getItems().add(e.getValue());
                            awayBox2.getItems().add(e.getValue());
                        }
                        x++;
                    }
                    System.out.println("\nMatch created between "+ homeTeam + " & "+ awayTeam);
                }
            }
            bool = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: We will need a bit more info to help you here. Ex. what is in your teamPlayers map?

Comment: Think in steps. 1. Get the home team players. 2. Get the away team players. 3. Add home team players to the home box. 4. Add away team players to away the away box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to generate matches based on the teams in your `HashMap`.

Firstly, you didn't explain the structure of your teamPlayers `HashMap`, but I believe your problem lies in how you use a `HashMap` to store your players.
You store them as {TeamName = PlayerName} combination, but like any `Map` the **key has to be unique**.
So you are probably dropping Players when initializing your `Map`:

```
Map<String, String> teamPlayers = new HashMap<String, String>();
teamPlayers.put("Team 1", "Player 1");
teamPlayers.put("Team 1", "Player 2");    // --> overwrites Player 2
teamPlayers.put("Team 2", "Player 3");
teamPlayers.put("Team 2", "Player 4");    // --> overwrites Player 3 
System.out.println(teamPlayers);
```

Prints out

> {Team 1=Player 2, Team 2=Player 4}

It would be better to add them as a `List`, this way every player is stored in the same `Entry`

```
Map<String, List<String>> teamPlayers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
teamPlayers.put("Team 1", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Player 1", "Player 2" }));
teamPlayers.put("Team 2", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Player 3", "Player 4" }));
System.out.println(teamPlayers);
```

Prints out

> {Team 1=[Player 1, Player 2], Team 2=[Player 3, Player 4]}

---

Secondly, if you want to generate matches with the combination of the teams in your teamPlayers `Map`, then you need to take a different approach.
It would be better to split everything up:

1. Initialize your players grouped in a `List`
2. Initialize the possible Match combinations
3. Initialize your GUI `ComboBox` for a certain Match combination

A runnable example class to help you on the way would look like this.

```
public class MatchFixer {

    private Map<String, List<String>> teamPlayers;

    public MatchFixer() {
        teamPlayers = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        teamPlayers.put("Team 1", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Player 1_1", "Player 1_2" }));
        teamPlayers.put("Team 2", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Player 2_1", "Player 2_2" }));
        teamPlayers.put("Team 3", Arrays.asList(new String[] { "Player 3_1", "Player 3_2" }));
    }

    public List<Match> generateMatches(){
        List<Match> matches = new ArrayList<Match>();
        for (String homeTeam : teamPlayers.keySet()){
            for (String awayTeam : teamPlayers.keySet()){
                if (!homeTeam.equals(awayTeam)){
                    Match match = new Match(homeTeam, awayTeam);
                    matches.add(match);
                    System.out.println("\tMatch created between "+ homeTeam + " & "+ awayTeam);
                }
            }
        }
        return matches;
    }

    public void initMatch(Match match){
        String homeTeam = match.getHomeTeam();
        String awayTeam = match.getAwayTeam();

        List<String> homePlayers = teamPlayers.get(homeTeam);
        List<String> awayPlayers = teamPlayers.get(awayTeam);

        scoreHomeTeam.getItems().add(homeTeam);
        scoreAwayTeam.getItems().add(awayTeam);

        homeBox.getItems().addAll(homePlayers);
        homeBox2.getItems().addAll(homePlayers);
        awayBox.getItems().addAll(awayPlayers);
        awayBox2.getItems().addAll(awayPlayers);

        System.out.println("\tMatch initialized between "+ homeTeam + " -> "+ homePlayers +" & "+ awayTeam +" -> "+ awayPlayers);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MatchFixer fixer = new MatchFixer();

        // Initialize matches with all the combinations of teams
        System.out.println("Initialize the match combinations:");
        List<Match> matches = fixer.generateMatches();

        // Let's initialize the first of our generated matches
        System.out.println("\nInitialize match 1:");
        fixer.initMatch(matches.get(0));
    }
}
```

Prints out

> Initialize the match combinations:
>
> > Match created between Team 3 & Team 1
> >     Match created between Team 3 & Team 2
> >     Match created between Team 1 & Team 3
> >     Match created between Team 1 & Team 2
> >     Match created between Team 2 & Team 3
> >     Match created between Team 2 & Team 1
>
> Initialize match 1:
>
> > Match initialized between Team 3 -> [Player 3_1, Player 3_2] & Team 1 -> [Player 1_1, Player 1_2]

Comment: Good Job @George Derpi. I assumed that the `Key` values were a list of `Players`.

Comment: Thank you mate, really i appreciate it!